# Numbering to the right end of page

Tags: formatting, openoffice, documents

**How can I put the content** (like formula, figure) **numering to the right edge of the page?** I've seen it in many places, but can't seem to find how to do this the right way in OpenOffice.org writer.

Here is a screenshot from a PDF file, about what I'm talking about:
[image]

My biggest problem is with formulas, because they can not be resided, but after applying a numbering (and with it automatically a frame as well), the frame keeps the numbering close to it, if extended the formula is enlarging as well. I don't want to use manual numbering, because I have many formulas and reference it many times in document and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use invisible tables both for images and formulas. I simply copy the numbering field to desired table cell and for next formula I always use a copy of the first one. Works nice for me. :-)

Comment: Nice idea I'll try this out. Haven't thought of copying the numbering out from frame.

Comment: It's working. Cutting and pasting the numbering to the text document does not change it's behaviour. Thanks a lot.